# Magento 2 Static Content Deploy is Not working

Tags: magento2, cli, static-content-deploy

I'm using Magento 2.2.3. I am trying to do the Static Content Deploy through CLI in my Lampp.

This is the code I'm used, `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` or `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`.

It is showing the [this error](https://pastebin.com/XXjiE0bG).

I tried the below commands:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
rm -rf var/* pub/static/* generated/*
sudo chmod -R 777 var/* pub/* generated/* app/etc/*
sudo chmod -R 777 var/ pub/* generated/ app/etc/*
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy *or* php bin/magento
setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Comment: Is that 'booking/stylish' exist?

Comment: share your that theme configuration files.

Comment: You have added any custom css in any xml of html ?

Comment: Yes. Its our Custom CSS and HTML.

Comment: Is those file folders readable or accessible for web server user?

Comment: @kunj, Yes Those are readable and accessable.